# Not able to send Mail via simple bootstrap modal windows

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap, email, bootstrap-modal

I am having a onload pop up of modal window which have a signup button clicking which opens a new modal which has a form which when submits should send a mail to the specified e-mail address. Following is the script written by me. I was able to test it succesfully on our internal servers but not able to so on this domain:     [Wordlywise.som.sg](http://worldlywise.com.sg/)

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
     {



       $recipient="name@example.com";
        $subject="New Signup entry";
        $sender=$_POST["name"];
        $school=$_POST["school"];
        $senderemail=$_POST["email"];
        $mailBody="Name: $sender\nEmail: $senderemail\n\n$school";
        if(mail($recipient, $subject, $mailBody, "From: $sender <$senderemail>"))
        {
           echo "Thanks! Your Mail has been sent";

        }
     }
        ?>
```

Please let me know what I need to change in the script?

Comment: so.. if you put this code outside the modal.. it works?

Comment: Missing `}` in your code

Comment: `}` is there. I have edited the code

Comment: @Ethaan It's not about modals. I have tested this on our internal domains with modals there and it works fine.

Comment: your server is probably not configured correctly to send mail. (use phpinfo() to see your configurations). Check the error log for clues. Create a little script to send mail and call it directly, just to check if that works..

Comment: headers are off compared to my internal servers. What else i need to check.. Is there any SMTP check I need to perform?